# Creating filters with combination of AND and OR rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, active-record-query

I am in a situation to filter the records based on some conditions(conditions are in the form of scopes). in user model

```
scope :has_email, -> { where('email IS NOT NULL') }
scope :email_contains, (email) -> { where("email ILIKE :email'", email: email)}
```

If I want both conditions to be combined with 'AND' operator, We can do something like,

```
User.has_email.email_contains
```

The query generated would be

```
SELECT "user".* FROM "user" WHERE (email ILIKE '%gmail.com%') AND (email IS NOT NULL)
```

How can I proceed if I need scopes to be combined with `OR` operators? I found that rails 5 added support to `or` method(https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/05/30/rails-5-adds-or-support-in-active-record.html), But this won't work if we use includes or joins

Eg: `User.has_email.or(User.some_scope).or(User.joins(:event).temp)`

How do I join scopes with `OR`?

Comment: but in the example given above if the email is NULL why would one want to do check the value of email if we know its NULL?

Comment: My use case is very complex, I just want to explain the logic which I needed.

Comment: Hmm ok. You could do OR in a single scope though.
Not really sure if there is a way to OR while cascading scopes though.

Answer (score 1):

The bit you are missing is that a join is *forcing* the association to exist. To prevent that, you use `left_joins`:

```
User.left_joins(:event).where(event: {foo: bar})
```

Still it won't solve the issue because the `.or` method will work (by documentation) only on structurally equivalent relations.

You can actually overcome it by going one step lower, to Arel:

```
rels = [User.foo, User.bar(baz), User.joins(:event).temp]
cond = rels.map { |rel| rel.where_values.reduce(&:and) }.reduce(&:or)
User.left_joins(:event).where(cond)
```

The `where_values` property is an array of Arel::Nodes::Node instances, all of which are normally `and`-ed to get your query. You have to `and` them by hand, and then `or` the results.

If something does not work as expected, check the output of `cond.to_sql` in case you have missed something.